# How to sort data using MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I'm currently trying to use MongoDB Compass to query my collection. However, I seem to be only able to filter the data.

Is there any way for me to sort the data as well? I would like to sort my data in ascending order using one of my data fields.

If MongoDB Compass isn't the best way to order a collection, what other GUI could I use?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Your question in it's current form is likely too general to get an answer. Show what you have tried and what is going wrong - see the link below for some details. Good luck, and happy hacking!
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Using MongoDB Compass 1.7 or newer, you can sort (and project, skip, or limit) results by choosing the **Documents** tab and expanding the **Options**.

[image]

To sort in ascending order by a field `myField`, use `{ myField:1 }`. Any of the usual [cursor sort()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) options can be provided, including ordering results by multiple fields.

Note: options like sort and skip are not available in the default **Schema** tab because this view uses sampling to find a random set of documents, as opposed to the **Documents** view which displays a specific query result.

Comment: ascending is: 1 and descending is: -1

Comment: that works, how to sort string number like ['1', '2', '3']